# writing audio and video into mpeg-4

Tags: video, mpeg-4

any helpfull documents are available in web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC Player is an easy and useful tool (and it's free) for not only playing video, but also to convert video into different formats. Audacity is a good free tool that does that for audio.

Comment: hi djrsargent the real scenario is ,i want to write this from an input stream(rtp) video is encoded as h263 and audio as pcm ,now i want to multiplex this audio and video and write into a mpeg-4 format